# Middleware логгер Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, php5

Хочу сделать запись в логи действий пользователя:

```
switch ($request->segment(2)) {
    case 'login':
        $request->method() != "POST" ?: \Log::info(auth()->user()->id .  ' user is login');
        break;
    case 'logout':
        \Log::info(auth()->user()->id . ' user is logout');
        break;
    case 'register':
        $request->method() != "POST" ?: \Log::info(auth()->user()->id . ' is register');
        break;
}
return $next($request);
```

При действии login выдает ошибку:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Добавил `$response = $next($request);` все работает, но хотелось бы улучшить код, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, дело в том, что если пользователь еще не существует, при попытке выполнить `auth()->user()->id`  и возникает ошибка. Короче правильнее проверять, есть ли пользователь в системе.